# How can I change the margins for only part of the text?

Tags: indentation

Sometimes the margins need to be changed for a particular page, paragraph, or other section of text.  For example, if I'm writing a letter and want the left margin to be almost at the right side of the page for the four lines of my address, or if I am combining prose with poetry and want the poems to be indented relative to the rest of the work.

What is the best way to change both left and right margins on the fly?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

There are several packages available on CTAN to do this. [`changepage`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/changepage) looks promising but you can find other alternatives by searching for "margins" or "changepage" on [ctan search](http://www.ctan.org/search).

With the `changepage` package, you can use the `adjustwidth` environment as follows:

```
\begin{adjustwidth}{left amount}{right amount}
\lipsum[2]
\end{adjustwidth}
```

For example, to remove 100pt from the margin on both sides, you would use

```
\begin{adjustwidth}{100pt}{100pt}
```

Comment: `changepage` seems to do just what I'm after, through the `\begin{adjustwidth}{left change length}{right change length}` environment.  Thanks!

Comment: A little more specifically, `\begin{adjustwidth}{50pt}{-200pt} XXX \end{adjustwidth}` adds 50pt to the left margin and subtracts 200pt from the right margin.

Comment: Those who use the `memoir` class wiil find it already defines the `adjustwidth` environment, so no additional package is needed.

Comment: David Z's solution works very well, as well as the one by Vivi. However, none covers footnotes, which remain within the standard page pargin of the rest of the document. Anyone knows how to have footnotes to be included?

Answer (score 124):

Here is how you can do it. Put the following in the preamble (before `\begin{document}`)

```
\def\changemargin#1#2{\list{}{\rightmargin#2\leftmargin#1}\item[]}
\let\endchangemargin=\endlist
```

then in the text you can use

```
\begin{changemargin}{<arg>}{<arg>} 
\end{changemargin}
```

where `<arg>` is the distance you want to include on the margin (the first one defines the right-hand side margin, and the second defines the left-hand side one).

So, for example, to add 0.5 cm to the margins on either side, you would have:

```
\begin{changemargin}{0.5cm}{0.5cm} 
%your text here  
\end{changemargin}
```

This is exactly how the command

```
\begin{quote}
\end{quote}
```

is defined, but with the  set to 1cm. The command quote can be used without having to load any packages, by the way.

Comment: Thanks Vivi. I take it you mean "where <arg> is the distance...", right?  Are there any advantages to this version over using a package such as `changepage`?

Comment: @Michael: Sorry, because of html the <arg> was not showing (though it was written). About the advantages over changepage, I really don't know. I have never used changepage and didn't even know it existed. I guess I need to try it out  :)  Have you tried the package yet? Is it good and straightforward?

Comment: I haven't used it for a specific purpose yet, but was able to figure out how to do what I asked for and test it out within minutes of seeing David's suggestion.  Some advantages claimed in the documentation that I haven't tested are: Correctly identifying left- and right-side pages if they are different; working inside floats; being able to change the top and bottom margins as well as left and right.

Comment: This is a very elegant solution. Works perfectly, even inside a float (which is where i needed it).

Comment: The command dont works if you use it with a long text running across pages in a document definided with not equals inner and outer margins.

Comment: There is a small issue with the code. It adds additional margin on the top and bottom (prominently top). So if I use \begin{equation} \end{equation}, it adds even more space top and bottom.

Comment: This did not work for me. One of arguments #1 and #2 gets gobbled but the other lies freeform in the text.

Comment: This is an elegant solution. As @RaffaeleSantoro points out it doesn't work with changing margins in a twoside layout.
Is there a solution where for instance left and right margin adjustments switches between even/odd pages?
Like the adjustwith*-command from the package changepage as mentioned in the respoonse above.

Comment: Vivi's solution works very well, as well as the one by David Z. However, none covers footnotes, which remain within the standard page pargin of the rest of the document. Anyone knows how to have footnotes to be included?

Answer (score 37):

With either one of the [`KOMA-Script`](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) classes or the package `scrextend` (which is part of `KOMA-Script`), you can use the `addmargin` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{scrextend}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

% Syntax: \begin{addmargin}[<left indentation>]{<indentation>}
\begin{addmargin}[4em]{1em}
\blindtext
\end{addmargin}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for that, that's exactly what i've been looking for for a while now.

Comment: N.B. If used within an enumerated environment, this will remove the enumeration, i.e. you can't use it to adjust the margin of enumerated items.

Answer (score 13):

Earlier versions of the `geometry` package did not allow to change the margins inside the document. The package `gmeometric` could help then.

Today `geometry` supports changing the margin inside the document by its commands `\newgeometry{...}` accepting the same `key=value` arguments and by `\restoregeometry`, see the manual of the current package version.

Comment: FYI: the `\newgeometry` and `\restoregeometry` commands cause a page break.

Answer (score 6):

what about the `\narrower` (TeX?) command? Is it ok to use even though it does not offer a very precise control?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3.5cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.6cm,right=3.6cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[4]
{\narrower\lipsum[4]
\par}
\lipsum[4]
\lipsum[4]
\lipsum[4]
\lipsum[4]
{\narrower\narrower\narrower \lipsum[4]
\par}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: \narrower will indent the text by one \parindent. For more precise control one can also use \hskip 10pt etc. Of course is ok if you only want to indent once. \narrower\narrower will indent both left and right.

Answer (score 4):

It might not answer the question directly, but:

There is a `letter` class:

```
\documentclass{letter}
```

for writing letters.

And for verse there is a package called...wait for it...verse:

```
\usepackage{verse}
```

As I said, it doesn't answer the specific question, but it might solve the two applications you want the solution for.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on [Vivi’s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/600/5161), it's possible to use the `list` environment and manually change all other list parameters to whatever values are in effect in the surrounding text:

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{addmargin}{mm}{
    \list{}{
        \UseName{@beginparpenalty}=0
        \UseName{@itempenalty}=0
        \UseName{@endparpenalty}=0
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{#1} % Use `setlength' so calc will evaluate expressions
        \setlength{\rightmargin}{#2}
        \labelwidth=0pt
        \labelsep=0pt
        \itemindent=\parindent
        \listparindent=\parindent
        \parsep=\parskip
        \topsep=0pt
        \partopsep=0pt
        \itemsep=0pt
    }
    \item[]
}{
    \endlist
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```