# Multicolumns with equation format

Tags: horizontal-alignment, formatting, multicolumn

I'm currently writing a summary for my semiconducter devices course and I'm trying to do it with Latex (just started today). I have the following problem:

I have two chapters with two formulas each. But they writing is too close together.
Here my first attempt:

```
\section{Quantum Theory of solids}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\subsection{Density of States} 
$D_c(E)=\displaystyle\frac{4\pi (2m^*_n)^{3/2}}{h^3}\displaystyle\sqrt{E-E_c}$\\
$D_v(E)=\displaystyle\frac{4\pi (2m^*_p)^{3/2}}{h^3}\displaystyle\sqrt{E_v-E}$

\columnbreak

\subsection{Fermi-Dirac Distribution}
$f_e(E)=\displaystyle\frac{1}{1-exp(\frac{E-E_F}{k_BT})}$\\
$f_h(E)=1-f_e(E)$

\end{multicols}
```

Which looks like this:
[image]

then i tried to add the command    \flushright like this:

```
\columnbreak

\begin{flushright}
\subsection{Fermi-Dirac Distribution}
$f_e(E)=\displaystyle\frac{1}{1-exp(\frac{E-E_F}{k_BT})}$\\
$f_h(E)=1-f_e(E)$
\end{flushright}
```

The result:
[image]

I would be really grateful if you were to help a noob like me to make this formation better.

PS: here is the full text

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\title{Semiconducter Devices}
\author{Jean-Marc Sujata}
\date{\today}
\maketitle
\newpage

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.25\textwidth} %this figure will be at the right
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{DC.png}
\end{wrapfigure}
\section{Unit Cells}
$package\ density = \displaystyle{\frac{N_{Atoms} \cdot V_{Atoms}}{V_{unit cell}}}$
\\
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
$Type$ & Atoms & r-a ratio & Volume\\ \hline
$simple\ cubic$ & $N=1$ & $2r=a$ & $V_a=\frac{\pi}{6}r^3$\\ \hline
$body\ centered$ & $N=2$ & $2r=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} a$ & $V_a=\frac{8\pi}{3}r^3$\\ \hline
$face\ centered$ & $N=4$ & $2r=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\cdot a$ & $V_a=\frac{16\pi}{3}r^3$\\ \hline
$simple\ cubic$ & $N=8$ & $2r=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}a$ & $V_a=\frac{32\pi}{3}r^3$\\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\includegraphics[width=8cm, height=2cm]{Faces.png}
\section{Quantum Theory of solids}
  \begin{multicols}{2}
    \subsection{Density of States}
    $D_c(E)=\displaystyle\frac{4\pi (2m^*_n)^{3/2}}{h^3}\displaystyle\sqrt{E-E_c}$

    \noindent $D_v(E)=\displaystyle\frac{4\pi (2m^*_p)^{3/2}}{h^3}\displaystyle\sqrt{E_v-E}$

    \columnbreak

    \subsection{Fermi-Dirac Distribution}
    $f_e(E)=\displaystyle\frac{1}{1-exp(\frac{E-E_F}{k_BT})}$

    \noindent $f_h(E)=1-f_e(E)$

  \end{multicols}


\end{document}
\
```

If it helps: I'm using Texmaker

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Thanks for posting some code. Could you complete it to make a small, compilable document? With just your document class and the packages your example needs. This means people can copy-paste-compile in order to see the problem and play with solutions. Makes it easier to answer and so encourages people to give you good answers!

Comment: Without knowing the document setting, in particular the text width, it's impossible to help.

Comment: Well, the `wrapfig` next to a `\section` is something that will *certainly* break things.

Comment: @egreg I thought so too. But the documentation actually claims that this should work - it just says it will look awful. I was sure that the documentation said differently...?

Answer (score 2):

***Note: This is an answer to the original question. It does not answer the current question.***

If I complete your code in a standard way, I don't see any problem. However, I have replaced `\\` by paragraph breaks and added `\noindent` just to avoid the problems which `\\` in regular text mode can cause.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
  \section{Quantum Theory of solids}
  \begin{multicols}{2}
    \subsection{Density of States}
    $D_c(E)=\displaystyle\frac{4\pi (2m^*_n)^{3/2}}{h^3}\displaystyle\sqrt{E-E_c}$

    \noindent $D_v(E)=\displaystyle\frac{4\pi (2m^*_p)^{3/2}}{h^3}\displaystyle\sqrt{E_v-E}$

    \columnbreak

    \subsection{Fermi-Dirac Distribution}
    $f_e(E)=\displaystyle\frac{1}{1-exp(\frac{E-E_F}{k_BT})}$

    \noindent $f_h(E)=1-f_e(E)$

  \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: two columns]

But you might be best served by one of the environments provided by `amsmath`. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol,mathtools}

\begin{document}
  \section{Quantum Theory of solids}
  \begin{multicols}{2}
    \subsection{Density of States}
    \begin{equation*}
      \begin{gathered}
        D_c(E)=\displaystyle\frac{4\pi (2m^*_n)^{3/2}}{h^3}\displaystyle\sqrt{E-E_c}\\
        D_v(E)=\displaystyle\frac{4\pi (2m^*_p)^{3/2}}{h^3}\displaystyle\sqrt{E_v-E}
      \end{gathered}
    \end{equation*}
    \columnbreak
    \subsection{Fermi-Dirac Distribution}
    \begin{equation*}
      \begin{gathered}
      f_e(E)=\displaystyle\frac{1}{1-exp(\frac{E-E_F}{k_BT})}\\
      f_h(E)=1-f_e(E)
      \end{gathered}
    \end{equation*}
  \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: gathered equations]

Comment: Perhaps an en dash would be better for Fermi`--`Dirac?

Comment: oh, the spacing in the second subsection head is dreadful!  that should be (at least) ragged right!  {since it's only one line, and not that much too wide, i'd be inclined to `\rlap` the last word.)

Comment: what about using `align` for the equations (with alignment on =)?

Comment: @Guido I was guessing that the OP was using inline maths to avoid alignment and numbering, so I tried to use something which would respect that decision.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I agree. But since this is clearly not the layout the OP is using, I was not inclined to spend too much time cleaning it up.

Comment: @Christopher Hmmm... I would use just a hyphen `-` there. I tend to use `--` for ranges of numbers, for example, and `---` for dashes as punctuation. However, I might just be punctuating everything wrongly - I'm not sure what the correct usage is.

Comment: I wasn't sure myself, I just thought as it is two separate names. `:)`

Comment: Thank you all for your contribution!
@greg I will remember to post the whole part.
@ cfr Thanks for your efforts, sadly I still have the same problem. If it's ok I give you the whole text. (I will look into the notation of amsmath. I've updated the full code in the original post. Thanks again to all of you!

Comment: @barbarabeeton If I use `\rlap` on the last word, I get an extra vertical space. I thought that `\rlap` was supposed to not take space? (Only because I just found [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6304/). It is not a long-standing belief.)

Answer (score 1):

***This is an answer to the revised question. It involves issues not evident in the original question.***

You cannot use `wrapfigure` without ensuring that there is sufficient text in regular paragraphs to accommodate it. In particular, you can't use it too near things like lists and other special environments, such as `multicols`.

I would use `minipage` environments to handle this layout by hand. I also recommend `booktabs` for the table and the use of the `amsmath` environments, with `mathtools` enhancements.

However, I'm not sure what to do about the second subsection heading....

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol,mathtools,booktabs}

\begin{document}

  \section{Unit Cells}
  \begin{minipage}{.75\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{equation*}
        package\ density = \frac{N_{Atoms} \cdot V_{Atoms}}{V_{unit cell}}
    \end{equation*}

    \begin{tabular}{*{4}{c}}
      \toprule
      $Type$ & Atoms & r-a ratio & Volume\\ \midrule
      $simple\ cubic$ & $N=1$ & $2r=a$ & $V_a=\frac{\pi}{6}r^3$\\
      $body\ centered$ & $N=2$ & $2r=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} a$ & $V_a=\frac{8\pi}{3}r^3$\\
      $face\ centered$ & $N=4$ & $2r=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\cdot a$ & $V_a=\frac{16\pi}{3}r^3$\\
      $simple\ cubic$ & $N=8$ & $2r=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}a$ & $V_a=\frac{32\pi}{3}r^3$\\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \medskip

    \includegraphics[width=8cm, height=2cm, keepaspectratio=true]{Faces}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}{.25\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{DC.png}
  \end{minipage}

  \section{Quantum Theory of solids}
  \begin{multicols}{2}
    \subsection{Density of States}
    \begin{flalign*}
        D_c(E)&=\frac{4\pi (2m^*_n)^{3/2}}{h^3}\sqrt{E-E_c}\\
        D_v(E)&=\frac{4\pi (2m^*_p)^{3/2}}{h^3}\sqrt{E_v-E}
    \end{flalign*}
    \columnbreak
    \subsection{Fermi-Dirac Distribution}
    \begin{flalign*}
        f_e(E)&=\frac{1}{1-exp(\frac{E-E_F}{k_BT})}\\
        f_h(E)&=1-f_e(E)
    \end{flalign*}
  \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: equation groups in two columns]