# How to have two left margins at different points on one page?

Tags: spacing, formatting, margins

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change the margins for only part of the text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/588/how-can-i-change-the-margins-for-only-part-of-the-text)

I have managed to get what I want with changepage, but was wondering if there is an easier or more elegant way to get a name and address with a horizontal bar beneath at a 1in left margin and then have the rest of the letter (using letter.cls) with 1.5in left and right margins.

Here is my code that accomplishes what I am intending.  Let me know what your solutions might be.  Thanks.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{letter} 
% the following commands control the margins:
\topmargin=-1in    % Make letterhead start about 1 inch from top of page 
\textheight=8in  % text height can be bigger for a longer letter
\oddsidemargin=36pt % leftmargin is 1.5 inches
\textwidth=5in   % textwidth of 5in leaves 1.5 inches for right margin

\usepackage{changepage,lipsum}

\date{22 June 2012}

\begin{document}
\signature{Anthony}           % name for signature 
\longindentation=0pt                       % needed to get closing flush left
\let\raggedleft\raggedright                % needed to get date flush left


\begin{letter}{
Miss Gertrude Bennett \\
231 Sycamore Street \\
Staunton Virginia \, 24401
}

\begin{adjustwidth*}{-0.5in}{-0.5in}
\begin{flushleft}
{\Large\bf Richard Bennett}
\end{flushleft}
 {\large 11 Suffolk Down \quad $|$ \quad Shoreham New York \, 11786 \\
  }
\rule{6.5in}{2pt}
\vspace{6\parskip}
\end{adjustwidth*}

\opening{Dear Aunt Gertrude,} 

Well, I am supposed to by writing you a letter, eh?  The problem is knowing what to put in it.  I guess I could start off with telling you what I have done.  But, that's not going to take up very much space.  I don't do much else except sleep, work, and eat.  And, I have been doing a good job at eating it seems.  What you are losing, well, I am gaining.  So it goes.  I had to go up two sizes in pants and a size or two in shirts.  I weigh over 200 lbs.\ now.  It's hard to believe.  I used to weigh 155 lbs., and then it just started creeping up and up and up.  I don't feel like I am eating a whole lot of food, but I guess I am making poor choices of what foods to eat.  That must be the problem.  For example, I am like my father with cereal.  I eat that with half and half.  


\vspace{3\parskip}


\closing{Love,} 


%\ps{P. S\@.   Here is a postscript.} 
%\encl{}                % Enclosures

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! A hint: By indenting your lines of LateX code by four spaces -- easily achieved by highlighting the lines in question and clicking on the `{}` "button" above the editing window -- you can get the site to pretty-print the code.