# How to make fbox fit automatically around wide equations using empheq package

Tags: empheq

Is there a trick to make `fbox` used with `empheq` fit around the equations, even if they are too wide, or does not have to manually enter numerical values for sizes in this case?

One set of my equations I'd like to put a box around are too wide, and I get this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{article}%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[box=\fbox]{align*}
\frac{v}{r}  & =2.651e^{-0.055268t}+0.4867e^{-56.5025t}+7.849e^{-0.4218t}
\left(  \cos\left(  2.2873t+\SI{80.15}{\degree}\right)  +\sin\left(  2.2873t+
\SI{80.15}{\degree}\right)  \right)  \\
%
\frac{p}{r}  & =-0.4348e^{-0.055268t}+\overset{\text{compare to g=0
below}}{\overbrace{168.36e^{-56.5025t}}}+1.543e^{-0.4218t}\left(  \cos\left(
2.2873t-\SI{98.95}{\degree}\right)  +
\sin\left(  2.2873t-\SI{98.95}{\degree}\right)  \right)  \\
%
\frac{r}{r}  & =e^{-0.055268t}+e^{-56.5025t}+e^{-0.4218t}\left(
\cos2.2873t+\sin2.2873t\right)  \\
%
\frac{\phi}{r}  & =133.09e^{-0.055268t}-50.4e^{-56.5025t}+11.22e^{-0.4218t}
\left(  \cos\left(  2.2873t-\SI{199.39}{\degree}\right)  
+\sin\left(  2.2873t-\SI{199.39}{\degree}\right)  \right)
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

I've seen couple of related questions, but too complicated for me to follow. I hope there is a *simple* way to just tell Latex to make the box as wide as needed? May be I should be using something other than `fbox` in this case?

Comment: I guess that something like `\tikzmark` is better; but I wouldn't typeset such a thing for any amount of money.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really automatic, but the result seems near to what you want. But I'd do this in my document for no amount of money.

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,empheq}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[box=\mbox]{align*}
\tikzmark{A}
\frac{v}{r}  & =2.651e^{-0.055268t}+0.4867e^{-56.5025t}+7.849e^{-0.4218t}
\left(  \cos\left(  2.2873t+\SI{80.15}{\degree}\right)  +\sin\left(  2.2873t+
\SI{80.15}{\degree}\right)  \right)  \\
%
\frac{p}{r}  & =-0.4348e^{-0.055268t}+\overset{\text{compare to g=0
below}}{\overbrace{168.36e^{-56.5025t}}}+1.543e^{-0.4218t}\left(  \cos\left(
2.2873t-\SI{98.95}{\degree}\right)  +
\sin\left(  2.2873t-\SI{98.95}{\degree}\right)  \right)  \\
%
\frac{r}{r}  & =e^{-0.055268t}+e^{-56.5025t}+e^{-0.4218t}\left(
\cos2.2873t+\sin2.2873t\right)  \\
%
\frac{\phi}{r}  & =133.09e^{-0.055268t}-50.4e^{-56.5025t}+11.22e^{-0.4218t}
\left(  \cos\left(  2.2873t-\SI{199.39}{\degree}\right)  
+\sin\left(  2.2873t-\SI{199.39}{\degree}\right)  \right)\tikzmark{B}
\end{empheq}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw ([shift={(-.2em,3.5ex)}]pic cs:A) rectangle ([shift={(1.6em,-2.5ex)}]pic cs:B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works. I had to compile the file more than one time to see the frame around for some reason. Nice idea of using \end{tikzpicture}. How to remove all the other frames and lines that are showing up and just leave the frame around the equations?

Comment: @Nasser: Yeah, I prefer to use the `tikzmark` solution for drawing as well, and all `tiksmark` will require _at least_ two runs to stabilize.

Comment: @Nasser The other frames are made by `geometry`, I used them to show the page frame. Just remove the call to the `geometry` package (or, if you use it, the `showframe` option).

Comment: @egreg why would you not want to do this for your own documents?

Comment: @Jörg A display that spills into both margins? No way. `;-)`

Comment: Ah, yes. I thought you meant some technical limitation...

Answer (score 4):

### Not Recommended:

One solution would be to change the margins *before* and _after the `empheq`. Below I have applied the solution from [How can I change the margins for only part of the text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/588/how-can-i-change-the-margins-for-only-part-of-the-text) to adjust the margins:

[image]

However, I would *recommend* the `alignat*` solution below.

### Notes:

- [The `showframe` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showframe)
  was used just to show the page margins. It is not needed in your actual use.
- It is definitely an *not* automatic aolution, and I do now know why the margins had to be tweaked to be asymmetric in the use of the `ChangeMargin` environment.

---

### Recommended Solution:

While this does *not* really answer your question, I would recommend you re-format the equations so that are more readily parasable by humans by aligning the appropriate points:

[image]

### Notes:

- I also added some vertical space between the equations via the optional parameter to `\\`.
- `\llap` was used so that the `\overset` does not effect the alignment.

---

### Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{article}%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{showframe}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/588/how-can-i-change-the-margins-for-only-part-of-the-text
\def\ChangeMargin#1#2{\list{}{\rightmargin#2\leftmargin#1}\item[]}%
\let\endChangeMargin=\endlist%

\begin{document}

\begin{ChangeMargin}{-10.0em}{-20.0ex}%
\begin{empheq}[box=\fbox]{align*}
\frac{v}{r}  & =2.651e^{-0.055268t}+0.4867e^{-56.5025t}+7.849e^{-0.4218t}
\left(  \cos\left(  2.2873t+\SI{80.15}{\degree}\right)  +\sin\left(  2.2873t+
\SI{80.15}{\degree}\right)  \right)  \\
%
\frac{p}{r}  & =-0.4348e^{-0.055268t}+\overset{\text{compare to g=0
below}}{\overbrace{168.36e^{-56.5025t}}}+1.543e^{-0.4218t}\left(  \cos\left(
2.2873t-\SI{98.95}{\degree}\right)  +
\sin\left(  2.2873t-\SI{98.95}{\degree}\right)  \right)  \\
%
\frac{r}{r}  & =e^{-0.055268t}+e^{-56.5025t}+e^{-0.4218t}\left(
\cos2.2873t+\sin2.2873t\right)  \\
%
\frac{\phi}{r}  & =133.09e^{-0.055268t}-50.4e^{-56.5025t}+11.22e^{-0.4218t}
\left(  \cos\left(  2.2873t-\SI{199.39}{\degree}\right)  
+\sin\left(  2.2873t-\SI{199.39}{\degree}\right)  \right)
\end{empheq}
\end{ChangeMargin}
\end{document}
```

---

### Code: `Recommended`

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{article}%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[box=\fbox]{alignat*=5}
\frac{v}{r}   &={} &2.651 e^{-0.055268t}   &+{} &0.4867e^{-56.5025t}                                                    &+{} &7.849e^{-0.4218t} &f(\SI{80.15}{\degree}) \\
\frac{p}{r}   &={} &-0.4348 e^{-0.055268t} &+{} &\overset{\llap{$\scriptstyle\text{compare to g=0 below}$}}{\overbrace{168.36e^{-56.5025t}}} &+{} &1.543e^{-0.4218t} &f(\SI{98.95}{\degree}) \\[2ex]
\frac{r}{r}   &={} &e^{-0.055268t}         &+{} &      e^{-56.5025t}                                                    &+{} &e^{-0.4218t}      &f(\SI{0}{\degree})     \\[2ex]
\frac{\phi}{r}&={} &133.09 e^{-0.055268t}  &-{} &  50.4e^{-56.5025t}                                                    &+{} &11.22e^{-0.4218t} &f(\SI{199.39}{\degree})
\end{empheq}
where
\[ f(x) = \cos\left(  2.2873t + x\right) + \sin\left(  2.2873t+
x\right)  \]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to cut 3 of the 4 equations that are too long to fit within the margins. That can be done with the `multlined` environment from the `\ mathtools` package (it's loaded by  `empheq, and it loads`amsmath`, so it is unnecessary to load both of them). I loaded  empheq with the`overload`option – which simplifies the typing, and defined a`widebox` command, that has a better looking result, in my opinion.

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{article}%
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage[overload]{empheq}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcommand*{\widebox}[2][1em]{\setlength{\fboxsep}{7pt}\fbox{\hspace{#1}$\displaystyle #2$\hspace{#1}}}
\begin{document}


\begin{align*}[box=\widebox]%\small
\frac{v}{r}  & = \begin{multlined}[t]
 2.651e^{-0.055268t}+0.4867e^{-56.5025t}\\+7.849e^{-0.4218t}
\left(  \cos\left(  2.2873t+\SI{80.15}{\degree}\right)  +\sin\left(  2.2873t+
\SI{80.15}{\degree}\right)  \right)
\end{multlined} \\[6pt]
%
\frac{p}{r}  & =\begin{multlined}[t]-0.4348e^{-0.055268t}+\overset{\text{compare to g=0
below}}{\overbrace{168.36e^{-56.5025t}}} \\ +1.543e^{-0.4218t}\left(  \cos\left(
2.2873t-\SI{98.95}{\degree}\right)  +
\sin\left(  2.2873t-\SI{98.95}{\degree}\right)  \right)
\end{multlined}  \\[6pt]
%
\frac{r}{r}  & =e^{-0.055268t}+e^{-56.5025t} +e^{-0.4218t}\left(
\cos2.2873t+\sin2.2873t\right)\\[6pt]
%
\frac{\phi}{r}  & = \begin{multlined}[t]133.09e^{-0.055268t}-50.4e^{-56.5025t}\\+11.22e^{-0.4218t}
\left(  \cos\left(  2.2873t-\SI{199.39}{\degree}\right)
+\sin\left(  2.2873t-\SI{199.39}{\degree}\right)  \right)
\end{multlined}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]