# Text left spacing (local "margin")

Tags: spacing, paragraphs, minipage

How can I add left space to a block of text? (see the attempts and pictures below)

I can think of two ways:

**minipage**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\noindent
\hspace{2em}%
\begin{minipage}{0.95\textwidth}
\lipsum[2-3]
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image: minipage]

Three problems:

1. I cannot use another minipage within that minipage (which I need in my usecase)
2. Indentation and paragraph spacing seem to change
3. What to pass as the width optional argument?

**enumitem**

Using `itemize` with the `enumitem` options:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}  % needed!

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{itemize}[label={},leftmargin=2em]
\item \lipsum[2-3]
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

It loses indentation and the paragraph spacing is a little different than the rest, but looks like much better:

[image: enumitem]

Anyhow, any other suggestion?

(Duplicate of: [How can I change the margins for only part of the text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/588/how-can-i-change-the-margins-for-only-part-of-the-text))

Comment: see this http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2639/71471

Comment: @touhami I probably shouldn't have used the term *margins*. This is not about *paper* margins. This is about *paragraph* margins. Consider the examples I submitted. I searched and I do not think this is a dup of any other question.

Comment: Of course it is, this question is very frequent. I linked Will Robertson's answer the environment `adjustwidth` is what you look for, you can also search (google) for `changemargin` environment. Now, the fact that the question is duplicate does not mean it's not good.

Comment: @touhami you are right. The question you referenced was about page margins, but one of the answers he received can indeed be used for my purpose. I have added one answer to this question that uses the two approaches you mentioned in your last comment. If you'd like to make it a dup of another question, consider this one instead: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/588/how-can-i-change-the-margins-for-only-part-of-the-text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a suggestion using the `addmargin` environment defined by [package `scrextend`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/scrextend).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{addmargin}[2em]{0em}
\lipsum[2-3]
\end{addmargin}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `scrextend` is a package to use some KOMA-Script Features like `addmargin` with other classes. Hence if you use a KOMA-Script class there is no need to load `scrextend`.

Comment: Perfect. They can even by placed inside each other.

Answer (score 2):

Considering @touhami's comment and [this answer from another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/588/how-can-i-change-the-margins-for-only-part-of-the-text), here is a MWE that uses two other approaches for local paragraph margins:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% \adjustwidth
\usepackage{changepage}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/600/34244
%\def\changemargin#1#2{\list{}{\rightmargin#2\leftmargin#1}\item[]}
%\let\endchangemargin=\endlist

% touhaim's suggestion:
\def\changemargin#1#2{\list{}{%
\setlength{\leftmargin}{#1}%
\setlength{\rightmargin}{#2}%
\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
\setlength{\parsep}{\parskip}%
\setlength{\itemindent}{\parindent}%
\setlength{\listparindent}{\parindent}%
}\item[]}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{adjustwidth}{4cm}{4cm}
\lipsum[2]
\end{adjustwidth}

\lipsum[3]

\begin{changemargin}{4cm}{4cm} 
\lipsum[4]
\end{changemargin}

\lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: you need to define it like this `\def\changemargin#1#2{\list{}{%
\setlength{\leftmargin}{#1}%
\setlength{\rightmargin}{#2}%
\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
\setlength{\parsep}{\parskip}%
\setlength{\itemindent}{\parindent}%
\setlength{\listparindent}{\parindent}%
}\item[]}`

Comment: @touhami, updated it with your suggestion. Anyhow, to any users out there: I would suggest you just use the package `changepage`. Always better to use a package because it has been more widely tested and is continuously updated.