# C++ code, change the font

Tags: fonts, listings

I am Google-ing now for a while but couldn't find the answer. So here are the questions again:

I am trying to include parts of my C++ source code into a LaTeX document, and right now I am using `\lstinputlisting[language=C++, firstline=37, lastline=40]` for this purpose, which seems pretty good for it. The only thing that annoys me is, that it seems impossible to 
a) change the font type of the source code in the text. (It looks like 1997 not like 2018 :/ ) 
b) widen the space between the text and the frame (background-colour)
Right now my example is like this:

```
\usepackage{listings}

    \lstset{ %
  backgroundcolor=\color{gray},  
  basicstyle=\rmfamily,
  breakatwhitespace=false,      
  breaklines=true,                
  captionpos=b,                    
  commentstyle=\color{mygreen}, 
  extendedchars=true,              
  frame=single,                   
  keepspaces=true,             
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},      
  language=c++,                 
  numbers=none,                
  numbersep=5pt,                   
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{blue}, 
  rulecolor=\color{mygray},        
  showspaces=false,               
  showtabs=false,                 
  stepnumber=5,                  
  stringstyle=\color{mymauve},    
  tabsize=3,                      
  title=\lstname                
}

\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting[language=C++, firstline=37, lastline=300]{../source/document.cc}

/end{document}
```

And I want to make it look more like, for example, Github now (here is a random Github page, representing how I want the code to look like: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/APIExample )

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! As to the wider box for your code, just insert in it in an `adjustbox` environment (from  package `chngpage`).

Comment: Thank you! 
In the meantime I also found this solution for the second part of the question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/588/how-can-i-change-the-margins-for-only-part-of-the-text
which also seems pretty much for what i was looking for.

Comment: Beauty is in the eye of the beholder. Without an example of what you mean, it's difficult to say anything about your problems. Please, add a minimal example.

Comment: thank you for the positive critics, i edited it to make my question more clear.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest `basicstyle=\ttfamily` (there are several monospaced fonts available) and also `columns=fullflexible`.

Here I guessed your colors and changed the background color to a much lighter gray.

Using `lstlisting` or `\lstinput` is equivalent as far as the output is concerned.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\colorlet{mygray}{black!30}
\colorlet{mygreen}{green!60!blue}
\colorlet{mymauve}{red!60!blue}

\lstset{
  backgroundcolor=\color{gray!10},  
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  columns=fullflexible,
  breakatwhitespace=false,      
  breaklines=true,                
  captionpos=b,                    
  commentstyle=\color{mygreen}, 
  extendedchars=true,              
  frame=single,                   
  keepspaces=true,             
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},      
  language=c++,                 
  numbers=none,                
  numbersep=5pt,                   
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{blue}, 
  rulecolor=\color{mygray},        
  showspaces=false,               
  showtabs=false,                 
  stepnumber=5,                  
  stringstyle=\color{mymauve},    
  tabsize=3,                      
  title=\lstname                
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
#include <tesseract/baseapi.h>
#include <leptonica/allheaders.h>

int main()
{
    char *outText;

    tesseract::TessBaseAPI *api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
    // Initialize tesseract-ocr with English, without specifying tessdata path
    if (api->Init(NULL, "eng")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize tesseract.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Open input image with leptonica library
    Pix *image = pixRead("/usr/src/tesseract/testing/phototest.tif");
    api->SetImage(image);
    // Get OCR result
    outText = api->GetUTF8Text();
    printf("OCR output:\n%s", outText);

    // Destroy used object and release memory
    api->End();
    delete [] outText;
    pixDestroy(&image);

    return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

An alternative is `minted`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{c++}
#include <tesseract/baseapi.h>
#include <leptonica/allheaders.h>

int main()
{
    char *outText;

    tesseract::TessBaseAPI *api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
    // Initialize tesseract-ocr with English, without specifying tessdata path
    if (api->Init(NULL, "eng")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize tesseract.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Open input image with leptonica library
    Pix *image = pixRead("/usr/src/tesseract/testing/phototest.tif");
    api->SetImage(image);
    // Get OCR result
    outText = api->GetUTF8Text();
    printf("OCR output:\n%s", outText);

    // Destroy used object and release memory
    api->End();
    delete [] outText;
    pixDestroy(&image);

    return 0;
}
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want a 21st century monospaced font, here's the result with `minted` after adding

```
\usepackage{sourcecodepro}

\setminted{fontsize=\footnotesize}
```

(or you could scale the font at the outset, with the specific option).

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the question i (still) have is: i dont like the font type thats written, and ttfamily does not look how i want it to look but i cant find a way to change it how i want it. For example if i want the text to be exacly like the text above, how and what would i change ? (to normal arial, to normal roman)
(And no, i do not like the ttfamily look, but beauty not a uniform thing ;)

Comment: @jpost Use `\rmfamily` instead of `\ttfamily`, for instance.

Comment: and there is the problem i tried to tell: i does not work. I spent over 4 hours trying to do it: it simply does not work. The font of the source-code is changed and there seems to be no way to change it back. i am really frustrated

Comment: @jpost Do you mean that eith `basicstyle=\rmfamily` the outcome doesn’t change?

Comment: I think using Consolas font or something similar was what OP was asking

Comment: @percusse I added the image (and a hint for the code) with Source Code Pro.