# How to remove weird symbol

Tags: spacing, pdftex, setspace

Hello from this question

[C++ code, change the font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/409705/c-code-change-the-font)

the first answer has given the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\colorlet{mygray}{black!30}
\colorlet{mygreen}{green!60!blue}
\colorlet{mymauve}{red!60!blue}

\lstset{
  backgroundcolor=\color{gray!10},  
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  columns=fullflexible,
  breakatwhitespace=false,      
  breaklines=true,                
  captionpos=b,                    
  commentstyle=\color{mygreen}, 
  extendedchars=true,              
  frame=single,                   
  keepspaces=true,             
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},      
  language=c++,                 
  numbers=none,                
  numbersep=5pt,                   
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{blue}, 
  rulecolor=\color{mygray},        
  showspaces=false,               
  showtabs=false,                 
  stepnumber=5,                  
  stringstyle=\color{mymauve},    
  tabsize=3,                      
  title=\lstname                
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
#include <tesseract/baseapi.h>
#include <leptonica/allheaders.h>

int main()
{
    char *outText;

    tesseract::TessBaseAPI *api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
    // Initialize tesseract-ocr with English, without specifying tessdata path
    if (api->Init(NULL, "eng")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize tesseract.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Open input image with leptonica library
    Pix *image = pixRead("/usr/src/tesseract/testing/phototest.tif");
    api->SetImage(image);
    // Get OCR result
    outText = api->GetUTF8Text();
    printf("OCR output:\n%s", outText);

    // Destroy used object and release memory
    api->End();
    delete [] outText;
    pixDestroy(&image);

    return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

But when compiling the program in the printing part the output looks weird as below
[image]

How do I remove that weird symbol between the letters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`listings` supports explicitly showing spaces in strings. You can deactivate this using `showstringspaces=false` (see the line with `<- ADDED`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\colorlet{mygray}{black!30}
\colorlet{mygreen}{green!60!blue}
\colorlet{mymauve}{red!60!blue}

\lstset{
  backgroundcolor=\color{gray!10},  
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  columns=fullflexible,
  breakatwhitespace=false,      
  breaklines=true,                
  captionpos=b,                    
  commentstyle=\color{mygreen}, 
  extendedchars=true,              
  frame=single,                   
  keepspaces=true,             
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},      
  language=c++,                 
  numbers=none,                
  numbersep=5pt,                   
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{blue}, 
  rulecolor=\color{mygray},        
  showspaces=false,               
  showstringspaces=false, % <- ADDED
  showtabs=false,                 
  stepnumber=5,                  
  stringstyle=\color{mymauve},    
  tabsize=3,                      
  title=\lstname                
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
#include <tesseract/baseapi.h>
#include <leptonica/allheaders.h>

int main()
{
    char *outText;

    tesseract::TessBaseAPI *api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
    // Initialize tesseract-ocr with English, without specifying tessdata path
    if (api->Init(NULL, "eng")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize tesseract.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Open input image with leptonica library
    Pix *image = pixRead("/usr/src/tesseract/testing/phototest.tif");
    api->SetImage(image);
    // Get OCR result
    outText = api->GetUTF8Text();
    printf("OCR output:\n%s", outText);

    // Destroy used object and release memory
    api->End();
    delete [] outText;
    pixDestroy(&image);

    return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you it worked!