# How can I change the margin for the text in all \subsections?

Tags: indentation

I use `\subsection*{title}` for the titles of my document, and then I write the text. The text have indentation on the beginning of the paragraph and the margin is the same for `\subsection*` and for the text.

I don't want the indentation (so I put `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` on the preamble), and I don't want the text to be aligned with my titles and that's the problem.

I  don't know how to change the left-margin just for text on `\subsection*`, on the preamble. Perhaps `titlesec` package can fix it but I don't know how to use it (and I don't know if I can use it on `article` class, all the posts I found for it is in `report` class).

Comment: How many `\subsection`s do you have like this? Is it something that necessarily has to be automated?

Comment: Yes, I use subsection all the time.

Comment: But if it can be a command, and work like `{\cmd my text}`, it would resolve the problem... Just change the left-margin of the global text without changing the margins of titles.

Answer (score 1):

I found something that satisfies me [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3597).
Here is my "`{\cmd my text}`" :
`{\narrower my text }`

I will use it like this

```
\newcommand{\nar}{\narrower}
{\nar my text }
```

It works with article class.

I didn't test it on my TeX files, I will do it later, if there is a problem I will report it here.

**BUT**, with this command, I can't change exactly the margin (with units).

So there is still a problem...

Comment: PROBLEM : the right margin is changed too.

Comment: The only solution I have is not the solution I want. [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1629/155050) is the only solution for the moment : `\usepackage{scrextend}` `\begin{addmargin}[2cm]{0cm}` where the 0cm is the right-margin... (Again I use `\newcommand{}{}` to be shorter).