# Narrow text in LaTeX

Tags: formatting, indentation, text

I strongly believe this is a duplicate but I didn't find any answers.

My rather simple problem is, that I want to have some part of my text on another textwidth. As seen in the picture below.

[image]

Comment: You have the  `quote` environment for that. If you need to further customise, see the `quoting` package.

Comment: The suggested answers do not mention the more flexible approach to narrowing (or widening) text provided the `adjustwidth` environment from the `changepage` package.

Comment: @PeterWilson: True. The duplicate should also be pointing to [How can I change the margins for only part of the text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/588/5764) I've added that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a `quote` as @Bernard said. There is a standard LaTeX environment for it `\begin{quote} .. \end{quote}`. There is also the `quotation` environment for use with longer quotations, of more than one paragraph, because it indents the first line of each paragraph. For more advanced requirements, there is the `quoting` package as also noted by @Bernard.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{quote}
\lipsum[2]
\end{quote}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]