# How to have line numbering inside of page frame?

Tags: multicol, lineno

When using `lineno` for linenumbering, the following code

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[columnwise]{lineno}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{adjmulticol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{2em}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    Text that exists outside of line numbering environment.
    
    \bigskip
    \begin{linenumbers}
        \blindtext

        \blindtext

        \blindtext
    \end{linenumbers}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

adds line numbers outside of the page frame, as shown below:

[image: Compiled code with line numbering outside of page frame within multicolumn environment]

I need the line numbers to appear *within* the frame, to the left of the column (no `switch` option).

I've tried `internallinenumbers`, but since I'm using columns with content that will occupy both columns, an environment like `parbox` won't work.

I've also tried the `adjmulticol` package to resize the columns, but it moves the entire columns' contents over, not just the content with line numbering.

Any thoughts on a viable solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do two things:

1. Adjust the margins of the numbered text. There are a number of ways to do this, but an easy one is the `addmargin` environment in KOMA-Script. (See [the answers to this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/588/how-can-i-change-the-margins-for-only-part-of-the-text) for other possibilities.)
2. Adjust the `\linenumbersep` length to pull the numbers over to where you want.

This answer uses a KOMA-Script class, but you can also get the same function from `scrextend` if you need a different document class.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\setlength{\columnsep}{2em}
\setlength{\linenumbersep}{-14pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    Text that exists outside of line numbering environment.

    \bigskip
    \begin{addmargin}[16pt]{0pt}
    \begin{linenumbers}
        \blindtext

        \blindtext

        \blindtext
    \end{linenumbers}
    \end{addmargin}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]