# math alignment in minipage

Tags: math-mode, minipage

I want the two equations to be *treated separately* i.e I want to follow-up the steps to formulate each equation till bottom of the page, on each `minipage` as defined. I tried using different math modes `\(...\)`, `\[...\]`, `\begin{align*}...\begin{align*}` etc. but **I get the equations (along with text) displayed at the center, right below each other.**

How can I fix this?

```
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}

\def\changemargin#1#2{\list{}{\rightmargin#2\leftmargin#1}\item[]}
\let\endchangemargin=\endlist 

\begin{document}

\begin{changemargin}{1in}{1in} 

\noindent \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}

Equation 1
\begin{align*}
    x+y=z 
\end{align*} 

\end{minipage}

\hfill

\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}

Equation 2
\begin{align*}
    a+b=c 
\end{align*} 

\end{minipage}

\end{changemargin}
```

References

1. [How can I change the margins for only part of the text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/588/how-can-i-change-the-margins-for-only-part-of-the-text)

Comment: Would you like the two `minipage`s to be set next to each other? Please advise.

Comment: YES, please provide your valuable input and feedback. I am learning through this website

Comment: Remove the blank lines between the two minipages.

Comment: a minipage is positioned like a letter you have blank lines between them so they are in separate paragagraphs one above the other

Comment: Ohh, got it! it works perfectly now. Thank you both

Comment: What’s the reason for `changemargin`?

Comment: @egreg, `.45\textwidth` would not have worked otherwise I guess, as my main L-R margins were `1.4in` each.

Comment: @b.kedar Twice 0.45=0.9, which is less than 1. I can't see the problem.

Comment: yes, first to make the margin 1in I used `changemargin`,

Answer (score 2):

You need to (a) delete the blank lines before and after `\hfill` and (b) change the instances of `\textwidth` to `\linewidth`. Why? Because `\textwidth` is not affected by the switch into a `list`-like environment, whereas `\linewidth` is.

The framelines in the following screenshot are inserted by the `showframe` package. The filler text before and after the `minipage` environments is generated by `\lipsum` directives.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,showframe,lipsum}
%\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}

\def\changemargin#1#2{\list{}{\rightmargin#2\leftmargin#1}\item[]}
\let\endchangemargin=\endlist 

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-5]

\begin{changemargin}{1in}{1in} 

\noindent 
\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
Equation 1
\[
    x+y=z 
\]
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
Equation 2
\[
    a+b=c 
\] 
\end{minipage}

\end{changemargin}

\lipsum[1][1-5]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was exactly looking for this `line-to-line` matching in `minipage`. Got to practically learn something new today about `\textwidth` versus `linewidth` which in simple words keeps a track every step performed in math mode. Thank you.